# DataTable Sort (upper, case, status) C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, powerbuilder

I have some problem with DataTable sorting.

I have some sorts in PowerBuilder script like `status_abbr A`. In C# it will be `status_abbr ASC`. But I don't how to interpret it in C# (DataTable Sort) such sort strings as `Upper(era_supp) A` and `case( status   when 'P' then 'O'   when 'Q' then 'O'   else status ) A`.

Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DataTable.CaseSensitive Property: It
indicates whether string comparisons within the table are case-sensitive. In your case you want it set to False.

You can alternatively add a calculated column in your DataTable and sort by that column. The column expression contains the mapping that you need.

A third option is to use the .OrderBy method, passing a lambda expression. You need to look this up in the Internet. There are plenty of example.